# What data rescaling preprocessing do I need to do before training an LSTM NN?

Tags: keras, scale, lstm, activation

I am trying to build a simple one layered LSTM neural network using keras that has a `Dense()` output layer with one neuron (used for regression).

I know that the training data when I `fit()` the model have to be rescaled. Many online examples rescale both the input and the output within the range [0,1], others within the range [-1,1].

What is the right choice for rescaling the input and the output for a simple regression problem like mine and why? I know it has to do with the activation functions used e.g. sigmoid outputs values within [0,1].

I have seen that you can select the activation function and recurrent activation. 
How are the activation functions implemented in the context of an `LSTM()` in keras (e.g. the input gate has a 'sigmoid')?

Thanks!

Comment: you would probably get an answer to this question on [this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), as this isn't a programming specific question, and has nothing to do with keras directly

Answer (score 0):

For scaling, I usually use the preprocessing.scale function from Scikit-Learn. It gives good results. For a deeper explanation [should I normalize/standardize/rescale](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/section-16.html)

For LSTM layers is advised to use "RELU" activation function it helps with vanishing gradient problem check this answer: [advantages of RELU](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126238/what-are-the-advantages-of-relu-over-sigmoid-function-in-deep-neural-networks). For your second layer (last) use linear activation since  you doing regression, if you were doing classification then use "sigmoid".